# Sorting with children in select2

Tags: javascript, sorting, jquery-select2

**Short version**

Children don't get sorted with my custom sort function in select2.

**Long version**

Suppose I have a select list containing the following options.

```
y
ay
aay
No
 ay
aaay
```

(Option 'No' has a child with the text 'ay'.)

When a search term is given, say 'y', the list is sorted by two things:

1. Position of search term (`y` appears in position 0 in the first option, and is in position 1 in the second option and so on)
2. Length of matching result (`y` is shorter than `ay` and so on)

Code:

```
results.sort( function(a, b) {
    a = a.text.toLowerCase();
    b = b.text.toLowerCase();
    var aIndex = a.indexOf(searchTerm);
    var bIndex = b.indexOf(searchTerm);
    if (aIndex > bIndex) {
      return 1;
    } else if (aIndex < bIndex) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      if (a.length > b.length) {
        return 1;
      } else if (a.length < b.length) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
})
```

So if I were searching for 'y', the resulting list should be this:

```
y
No
 ay
ay
aay
aaay
```

Instead however, option `No` appears first. `No`'s children do not ever go through my custom sort function, but its relevance to the search term is picked up by select2 anyway.

How do I make it so that the children of options get passed to the sort function? I know I can access `a.children` and such but how can I make it so that the children themselves get sorted properly too? Ex. if `No` had two more children, `aay` and `y` (in that order), the output of the whole list should be:

```
y
No
 y
 ay
 aay
ay
aay
aaay
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/813oetsh/1/)

Comment: You need to recursively call the sort function.

Comment: @TobiahRex Not sure how to use recursion on this, can you give an example/edit the fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed one scenario: when indexOf does not match searchTerm at all. In case of "No", it returns -1 and even that you evaluate it as best result. This example will in that case set value of second value or 0. Anyway it will result in equal and compare based on string length:

```js
var dataArray = [];

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  dataArray.push({
    id: i,
    text: "".padStart(i, "a") + "y"
  });
}

dataArray[3].text = "No";
dataArray[3].children = [{
  id: 6,
  text: "ay"
},{
  id: 7,
  text: "y"
},{
  id: 8,
  text: "aay"
},

];

var $output = $("#output");

$("#test").select2({
  data: dataArray,
  sortResults: function(results, container, query) {
    if (query.term) {
      var searchTerm = query.term.toLowerCase();
      return results.sort(function(a, b) {
        $output.append("<p>" + a.id + " and " + b.id + "</p>");
        a = a.text.toLowerCase();
        b = b.text.toLowerCase();
        var aIndex = a.indexOf(searchTerm);
        var bIndex = b.indexOf(searchTerm);
        // remember: indexOf could be also -1 ("No")
        aIndex = aIndex < 0 ? (bIndex > -1 ? bIndex : 0) : aIndex; 
        bIndex = bIndex < 0 ? (aIndex > -1 ? aIndex : 0) : bIndex; 
        var diff = aIndex - bIndex;
        if (diff == 0) {
         return a.length - b.length;
        }
        return diff;
      });
    }
    return results;
  }
});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>

<p>Click on the bar below and type 'y'.</p>

<input id="test" />

<div id="output">
  <p>The following options (IDs) were sorted (note that 'No's child has an ID of 6):</p>
</div>
```

NOTE: that each children will be sorted separatelly so you can't change based on results of children order of parent (or I don't know how).